# Remove old MongoDB documents

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql

Quite an interesting case. I have an enormous MongoDB collection with lots of documents. These are two of the fields ( I changed the field names).

```
{
"pidNumber" : NumberLong(12103957251), 
"eventDate" : ISODate("2018-05-15T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

I need to count all the instances where the date is older than 1 year but ONLY if there's a more recent document with the same pidNumber.

So for example:

> If there's only one document with pidNumber 1234 and it's from three
> years ago - keep it (don't count).
>
> But if on top of that there's another document with pidNumber 1234 and
> it's from two years ago - count the three years old one.

Is it possible to do? Does anyone have on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not fully clear what you are looking for but this might be a good starting point:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group:
         {
            _id: "$pidNumber",
            eventDate: { $max: "$eventDate" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
   },
   {
      $match: {
         $or: [
            { count: 1 },
            { eventDate: { $gt: moment().endOf('day').subtract(1, 'year').toDate() } }
         ]
      }
   }
])
```

Whenever one have to deal with date/time values I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library.